# I want to populate the column of a dataframe with values from the column of another dataframe when the values of two columns match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, populate

I want to populate values of `df2['VALUE']` in a new column in df1 `df1['New']` when category and location match for both dataframes.

When

`df1['category'] = df2['CATEGORY']`  AND `df1['location'] = df2['LOCATION']`

populate values of `df2['VALUE']` into a new row in df1 so that using `df1['v1']` I can calculate `df1['calculatedfield'] = df1['v1']/df1['new']`

**df1**

| category | location | type | v1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | loc1 | 1 | 2 |
| A | loc1 | 2 | 4 |
| A | loc2 | 1 | 6 |
| A | loc2 | 2 | 8 |
| B | loc1 | 1 | 10 |
| B | loc1 | 2 | 12 |
| B | loc2 | 1 | 14 |
| B | loc2 | 2 | 16 |

**df2**

| CATEGORY | LOCATION | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | loc1 | 50 |
| A | loc2 | 30 |
| B | loc1 | 70 |
| B | loc2 | 90 |

**output**

| category | location | type | v1 | new(df2['VALUE']) | calculatedfield(v1/new) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | loc1 | 1 | 2 | 50 | 0.04 |
| A | loc1 | 2 | 4 | 50 | 0.08 |
| A | loc2 | 1 | 6 | 30 | 0.2 |
| A | loc2 | 2 | 8 | 30 | 0.27 |
| B | loc1 | 1 | 10 | 70 | 0.14 |
| B | loc1 | 2 | 12 | 70 | 0.17 |
| B | loc2 | 1 | 14 | 90 | 0.16 |
| B | loc2 | 2 | 16 | 90 | 0.18 |

`df1` has more rows than `df2`, that is why I didn't go with joining the two dataframes. I need to populate `df2['new']` with the values from `df2['VALUE']` wherever the combination of category and location come up and regardless of the value of `df2['type']`. I can't drop rows.

I tried

```
df1['New'] = np.where((df1['category'] == df2['CATEGORY']) & (df1['location'] == df2['location']), df2['VALUE'], None)
```

and this came up:

**ValueError:** Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.set_index()` function to create a multiIndex dataframe for obtaining values from `df2` and use the `pandas.reset.index()` to reset the dataframe. Please see below my sample code. I have replicated your dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

### code:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
        'location': ['loc1', 'loc1', 'loc2', 'loc2','loc1', 'loc1', 'loc2', 'loc2'],
        'type': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,],
         'v1': [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]}
data2 = {'category': ['A', 'A','B', 'B'], 
        'location': ['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc1','loc2'],
        'VALUE': [50,30,70,90]}    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_temp = df1.set_index(['category','location'])
df_temp['New'] = df2.set_index(['category','location'])['VALUE']
df1 = df_temp.reset_index()

df1['Calculated_Field'] = df1['v1']/df1['New']
df1
```

### Output:

[image]

### References:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index

Comment: Thank you! It worked specifing the column names (they're different between df's) like this:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df_temp = df1.set_index(['category','location'])
df_temp['New'] = df2.set_index(['CATEGORY','LOCATION'])['VALUE']
df1 = df_temp.reset_index()

df1['Calculated_Field'] = df1['v1']/df1['New']
df1

Comment: Great, glad to hear that answers your question!